# my cocos2d game start, than other music applications stop

Tags: c++, cocos2d-android

When I start my Project game(using SimpleAudioEngine / cocos 3.16_ver / android Build / android Studio 3.0), than other music applications stop(ex. Samsung Music).
I want when i playing the game, listen My Music(not Game Background Music).

i did not modify android source.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in 3.16 version.
You should modify code in Cocos2dxActivity.java (`cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/java/src/org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxActivity.java`)

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume()");
    super.onResume();
    // issue #18465
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (!manager.isMusicActive()) {
        Cocos2dxAudioFocusManager.registerAudioFocusListener(this);
    }
    this.hideVirtualButton();
    resumeIfHasFocus();

    Cocos2dxEngineDataManager.resume();
}
```

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/18465#issuecomment-344135839